# I get the following error, when trying to use C# Lambda extension method All

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
private void EnsureCurrentlyValid()
{
    //I'm valid if IDataErrorInfo.this[] returns null for every property
    var propsToValidate = new[] { "Name", "Email", "Phone", "WillAttend" };
    bool isValid = propsToValidate.All(x => this[x] == null);
    if (!isValid)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't submit invalid GuestResponse");
}
```

---

'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'All' and no extension method 'All' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\dev\aspnet\PartyInvites\Models\GuestResponse.cs

---

What am I missing?

Comment: Try ReSharper and you'll never have that problem again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

[All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) is an extension method defined on Enumerable.  The extension methods (including All) are defined in the System.Linq namespace, so you need to include a using directive for System.Linq to your class in order to reference the extension methods.   You'll also need to be using C# 3.0 and .NET 3.5.